# Is it possible to get a file modification time in Stata?

Tags: stata

Suppose I have a database with file names and I would like add file modification dates and times to this database. Is it possible to do it in `Stata` in a straightforward way?

I can think of two non-straightforward ways:

- 1) Writing a plugin in `C` or `Java`.
- 2) Using `dir` command, capturing the output in a log file, and then importing that log file back.

But is there a less cumbersome solution?

There does not seem to be either a `Stata` or a `Mata` function that is of any help. I realize that I can easily do it in any scripting language and then import the results into `Stata` but I would like to know if there is a purely `Stata` solution (for portability reasons).

Comment: I believe not. See `help macro` and its links, but I am not aware of anything of that kind.

Comment: If you choose to write your own, the SSC `dirlist` package (`net describe dirlist, from(http://fmwww.bc.edu/RePEc/bocode/d)`) has what appears to be a (relatively) portable implementation.

Comment: You can use ashell to capture the results of a shell command: https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s456833.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that using the `shell` capabilities of Stata.
See here:

http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?shell